# magento: How to add a phtml block from the template to a CMS page

Tags: magento

i have a block in a template called "shopper". I want to add a block that's in 
"app\design\frontend\default\shopper\template\tag\popular.phtml".

I tried:

```
    {{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='tag/popular.phtml' }}
```

The block is not showing. No PHP error also.

Comment: you should always assign `id` attribute along with `type` and `template`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
{{block type="core/template" template="tag/popular.phtml"}}
```

If that doesn't work, make sure you clear cache (if any) and double check that 'shopper' is set to your default theme.

Read more @ http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/221573/

If the content of 'tag/popular.phtml' is the same or similar to base/template/tag/popular.phtml then try

```
{{block type="tag/popular" template="tag/popular.phtml"}}
```

Comment: "system>>Configuration>>Design>>themes>>Default" is now 'shopper'. Still no affect. I'm thinking that may be the theme is blocking every thing ?

Comment: Is the content of popular.phtml the same as /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/tag/popular.phtml?

Comment: the cache is DISABLED. the Default path has no tag folder, i copy the tag folder to there and no affect. I'm sure now that the theme `shopper` is blocking the blocks.  because there are no layout except `local.xml` and any xml I coped it to there had no affect.

Comment: Do you have any custom module install... if so try disabling them and try again.